# Qlikview SQL error

Tags: sql, sdk, odbc, qlikview

When I run Qlikview with a SQL query I am getting the following error:

> SQL##f - SqlState: S1000, ErrorCode: 1111, ErrorMsg: [DataDirect][ODBC OpenAccess SDK driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Exception executing ipExecute : java.lang.NullPointerException
>   oajava.service_now.Condition.getValue(Condition.java:107)
>   oajava.service_now.Condition.(Condition.java:35)
>   oajava.service_now.passthrough.LogicalExpression.describeLogicExp(LogicalExpression.java:29)
>   oajava.service_now.passthrough.LogicalExpression.(LogicalExpression.java:16)
>   oajava.service_now.passthrough.QueryExpression.(QueryExpression.java:41)
>   oajava.servic
>   SQL

The SQL query I am running is:

SQL
//Total dos registos na tabela incident_alert

```
   SELECT COUNT(number) as Total
   FROM   incident_alert;
```

SQL
//Total de registo na tablea de incident_alert com relacionamento válido na tabela incident

```
   SELECT COUNT(incident_alert.number)
   FROM incident_alert
   LEFT   JOIN   incident      ON     (incident_alert.dv_source_incident=incident.number);
```

SQL
//Registos validos na tabela incident_alert com relacao a tabela incident e com a data da passagem para massivo.

```
   SELECT incident_alert.number, incident.opened_at
   FROM incident_alert
   LEFT   JOIN   incident      ON     (incident_alert.dv_source_incident=incident.number)
   WHERE (incident_alert.number) NOT IN 
   (
                 SELECT DISTINCT incident_alert.number
                 FROM  incident_alert
                 INNER      JOIN   incident ON     (incident_alert.dv_source_incident=incident.number)
                 INNER         JOIN   sys_audit    ON     (incident.sys_id = sys_audit.documentkey)
                 WHERE sys_audit.fieldname = 'u_masiva' 
                 AND   sys_audit.oldvalue = 0
                 AND   sys_audit.newvalue = 1
   );
```

Concatenate
SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT incident_alert.number, incident_alert.dv_source_incident, sys_audit.sys_updated_on, sys_audit.fieldname, sys_audit.oldvalue, sys_audit.newvalue
   FROM  incident_alert
   INNER      JOIN   incident ON     (incident_alert.dv_source_incident=incident.number)
   INNER        JOIN   sys_audit    ON     (incident.sys_id = sys_audit.documentkey)
   WHERE sys_audit.fieldname = 'u_masiva' 
   AND   sys_audit.oldvalue = 0
   AND   sys_audit.newvalue = 1;
```

I am getting the error right after:

*SQL
//Registos validos na tabela incident_alert com relacao a tabela incident e com a data da passagem para massivo.*

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer and solution. I've updated the ODBC driver version to a newer one and it worked.